# Setting text color to inverted background color

Tags: css

Here is my fiddle, I want to set the text color to background color but inverted.

https://jsfiddle.net/6q34vf7o/16/

```
<div>
<span>Test</span>
</div>

div {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #000);
  width: 100vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

span{
  font-size: 30vh;
}
```

How can I do it?
I know there's a mix-blend-mode, but I don't know how to use it at here.

Comment: This question needs more details. But you can try adding `filter: invert(1);` to `span`.

Comment: What more details you needed?

Comment: Definition of inversion. Any specific color you want to invert to? If it's just a regular invert, you can use filter: invert(1)

Comment: @AliDemirci The problem with using `filter:` is that it severely interferes with how browsers render the page (with potentially significant performance implications) and it creates a new stacking-context too, which messes-up `z-index` ordering if you're not expecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #000);
  width: 100vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

span {
  font-size: 30vh;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `text-fill-color: transparent` and `background-clip: text` in order to make gradient work as `background-image` in text. In the background line, just change 'to right' by 'to left'.

```css
div {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #000);
}

span {  
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #000);
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #000);
  
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
text-fill-color: transparent;
    
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;    
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 85vh; height: 35vh;'><span style='font-size: 30vh; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;'>TEST</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #000);
  width: 100vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

span{
  font-size: 30vh;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The `invert` filter is not related to its background. Its related with its color (currently black by default). Example: If the text color is 'orange' the `invert` would change it to blue regardless of its background.